# Android-passing value from form login to new activity using data from MySQL

Tags: android

i'm new to android development, i would like to know how to pass value from login form to new activity, the value from MySQL....

please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use getText()  on login controls(textView,editText etc) and pass the the value with the help of Intents.Intents have putExtra() method in which you can set name/value pairs (like attributes in java) and these attributes can be retrieved on the next activity by getExtras() methods.Study the concepts of Intents first and then move to database.and android uses SQLite database.you can make use of Content providers also!
GooD LucK Androider !